# How to escape singlequote(') in azure logic app expression replace function

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure logic Apps, how can I escape single quotes(`'`) using a replace function?

I have a JSON payload where I have to replace a single quote(`'`) with a double quote(`"`).
The expression I've came up with looks like this:

```
replace(string(@triggerBody()),'/' ','/" ')
```

But my second expression to escape the single quote (`'`) isn't working.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this by using a double single quotation, `''` thanks to this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8668#issuecomment-389634188)

Answer (score 3):

**Summary for single and doubt quotes sharing with others.**

1. String containing single quote ', use extra single quote to escape:

   ```
   ''
   ```
2. String containing double quotes ", prefix with a forward slash to escape:

   ```
   \"
   ```
3. Original json (posted from postman):

   ```json
   {
       "name": "single''dds double\"te",
       "email": "special signle and double quotes",
       "password": "pp@pp"
   }
   ```
4. `console.log` result in sql query in Nodejs environment:

   ```
   INSERT INTO ztestTbl(name, email, passowrd) VALUES (N'single''dds double"te', N'special signle and double quotes', N'pp@pp')
   ```
5. String insert into the mssql db:

   ```
   single'dds double"te
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@replace(string(triggerBody()),''' ','\" ')
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This is now you do it. You need 2 single quotes inside the single quote

```
@replace(string(triggerBody()),'''' ','\" ')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problem escaping *single quote* in query parameter `concat`.  I resolved it by used double quote. Thanks to tips in this post.

```
concat('**Text1**', ''**'**' , '**text2**',''**'**')
```

resulted in :

```
Text1'text2'
```

Take a note of **four** single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To escape a single quote in logic app expressions I was able to solve by :

```
@replace(variables('myString'),'''', '\''')
```